# sending html post json array from android with utf 8 to php and input to database?

Tags: php, android, json, utf-8

i have done this befor but in my other project i didnt have utf8 values and i think that this what massing it up but am not sure

android send json array func:

```
 URL url = new URL(MainActivity.URL2);
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
                conn.setDoOutput(true);
                conn.setDoInput(true);
                Log.i("JSON", arr.toString());
                if (arr.length() > 0) {
                    DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

                    os.writeBytes(arr.toString());

                    os.flush();
                    os.close();
```

and php side:

```
$input=file_get_contents("php://input");

$arr = json_decode($input, true);


foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {


    $city=$value["city"];
    $street=$value["street"];
    $type=$value["type"];
    $neighborhood=$value["neb"];
    $floor=$value["floor"];
    $rooms=$value["rooms"];
    $size=$value["size"];
    $price=$value["price"];
    $query="INSERT INTO `d1`"
                         ." (`type`, `city`, `street`, `neighborhood`, `size`, `rooms`, `floor`, `price`) "
                         ."VALUES ('$type', '$city', '$street', '$neighborhood', "
        . "'$size', '$rooms', '$floor', '$price');";
    $mysqli->query($query);



  }
```

i tryd a few functions in php for utf8 decode non of them seem to help

 ini_set('default_charset', 'utf-8'); in php didnt help 
anyone run in to this problem with utf8? 
error i get :Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() 
the decode not returning json array

input sample :(part of the array)

```
{"price":"1,790,000 ʢ,"floor":"2","street":"ߢ֪֠ Ҩܔ 2","neb":" թ֞蠠鑩֟ ݦڕߢ,"type":"ԙ锢,"size":"100","rooms":"4","city":"鑩֟ ݦڕߢ},{"price":"1,170,000 ʢ,"floor":"4","street":"ԕӠᚑ 22","neb":" ᖔ אѠ ᑕꡐڜߠ Ґ衩Ң","type":"ԙ锢,"size":"117","rooms":"4","city":"Ґ衩Ң"}
```

saved to file with :

```
 $myfile = file_put_contents('testinput2.txt',$input , FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

Comment: Can you show us the output of `$input=file_get_contents("php://input");`?

Comment: bit long so i cut part of it:[{"price":"1,790,000 ʢ,"floor":"2","street":"ߢ֪֠ Ҩܔ 2","neb":" թ֞蠠鑩֟ ݦڕߢ,"type":"ԙ锢,"size":"100","rooms":"4","city":"鑩֟ ݦڕߢ},{"price":"1,170,000 ʢ,"floor":"4","street":"ԕӠᚑ 22","neb":" ᖔ אѠ ᑕꡐڜߠ Ґ衩Ң","type":"ԙ锢,"size":"117","rooms":"4","city":"Ґ衩Ң"}

Comment: i saved input like this  $myfile = file_put_contents('testinput2.txt',$input , FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);

Comment: Add it to your original post, not in the comments.

Comment: ok il update :)

Comment: i think this a string escape problem need to replace " and ' befor createing the jsonobject, still checking